# How to set background colour for a child item in ExpandableListView at runtime

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to set a background colour for a child item after it has been selected in expandablelistview, I want this colour to remain as the background as long as the user have selected the item if not it should remain white background.

I've searched the internet but I couldn't find the solution to my exact problem.

Here is what I have in my onChildClickListener

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            groupposition = groupPosition;
            childposition = childPosition;
childID = (int) listAdapter.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
            listAdapter.getChildView(groupPosition,childID,false,v,parent).findViewById(R.id.lblListItem).setBackgroundColor(0xFF697B5D);
            return false;
        }
 });
```

this is not working as expected as it is also setting background for some child item that have not been selected.
Your kind assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: try v.setBackground I guess.

Comment: @UmerAsif how exactly do you mean when you said I should try v.setBackground?

Comment: v is the view that gets clicked so you can set background or you could change it in adapter code.

Comment: @kris larson please do you have an idea on how to solve this?